# Macros in GNU screen?

Tags: gnu-screen, macros, command-line

I use the `screen` command line program in Linux all the time, and I looked through the man page but didn't find the answer to this (although maybe I just missed it):

What I want to do is have a single command that splits the current region, tabs to the new region, and opens a new screen in it.  I hoped there was some way to maybe go into command (colon) mode and do something like `split; focus down; screen` but that doesn't work. Any ideas? Is it possible to maybe bind a series of commands to a single `C-a` binding?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
register s ^aS^i^ac
bindkey ^a,, process s
```

From the depths of the screen manual:

> **register** [-e encoding] key string
>
> Save the specified string to the register key.  The encoding
>     of  the string can be specified via the -e option.  See also
>     the "paste" command.

and:

> **process** [key]
>
> Stuff the contents of the specified
>   register  into  screen's  input 
>   queue. If no argument is given you are
>   prompted for a  register name. The
>   text is parsed as if it had been typed
>   in  from  the  user's keyboard. This
>   command can be used ***to bind  multiple
>   actions to a single key***.

Comment: And you can put in newlines with `\n` and the escape (for vim) with `\033`. I guess you can push anything in

Answer (score 6):

You could also arrange some files this way:

**~/.myscreenmacro**:

```
split
focus down
screen
```

**~/.screenrc**:

```
bind e source $HOME/.myscreenmacro
```

This is a little clearer than the other ways.

Comment: This is a great tip! Perfect for one-off stuff sessions. For example, I had a vim recording that wouldn't repeat for some reason. I could only get it to go by hitting @q again and again (even @@ didn't work.) Created a text file with "stuff @q" repeated 100 times, then sourced the file and away we went!

Comment: You can also add in "sleep 0.1" if you need to tweak the timing.

Answer (score 4):

Screen's command `eval` is handy for creating this kind of macros:

```
screen -X bind e eval split 'focus down' screen
```

Commands expecting arguments (like `focus down`) need to be quoted (single or double).

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped me to map ' ' such that I enter copy mode and immediately start the marking (to behave as if I typed '[ '). This is what I put into .screenrc: `register s ' '
bind ' ' eval 'copy' 'process s'` (register and bind being on separate lines).

Answer (score 0):

To create a split, change focus, and create new window with one command, put this in `~/.screenrc` :

```
bind s eval "split" "focus down" "screen"
```

and use `control-a s`.

This uses `eval` as [described in the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Eval).